# How can a transistor be made smaller without changing the electric field?

Tags: integrated-circuit, electromagnetism

Every time they introduce a new process node with reduced feature size, they tend to reduce the core voltage. The reason why is that the reduced size results in larger electric fields if they do not reduce the voltage. Once the electric field goes beyond a certain value, it causes electromigration, where the metal atoms begin to be ripped from their locations in the same manner as a fuse. This can be mitigated somewhat by using different materials, but improved materials only reduce the effect. So can a transistor actually be made smaller without changing the electric field?

Comment: You already said how to do it: lower the applied voltage.

Comment: BTW, the reason for reducing core voltage isn't to reduce electromigration; it's to avoid zener breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field is given by voltage over distance. If you make the distance smaller (as a consequence of shrinking the device), and keep the voltage constant, the field increases.